# Creating a Mutex with CreateMutex(), and using SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES

Tags: c++, service, process, global, mutex

I'm coding with Visual Studio C++ 2010 and I am creating a `Global\` Mutex with `CreateMutex()`. You can use `CreateMutex()` like so:

`CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);`

with the first argument being the security attributes.

I know you can create your own security attributes as so:

```
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sDescriptor;
InitializeSecurityDescriptor(...);
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(...);
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sAttribute;
// set sAttribute's fields
...
...
...

CreateMutex(sAttribute, FALSE, NULL);
```

My problem is that I don't really UNDERSTAND why you need to make your own security descriptor and attributes when making the mutex. My question is:

- What are the real differences between the default security attribute (`NULL`) and creating your own as above?
- How does the security attribute created from one computer or process different from the that of another computer or process if the same exact code is ran?

and for further discussion, when creating the mutex with the default security attribute like `CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);` within a service and trying to open the same mutex with `OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, NULL);` from a user-application outside of the service, you get an error 5 from `OpenMutex()` which is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. When you add the created security attribute, you can successfully open the mutex from the user-application.

Why is this? My theory is because services are ran in session 0, and all other applications run in different sessions so the security attributes must be zero. But I don't truly understand what the difference between making a security attribute or using the default is. Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: Have you seen this article? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686670(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks for the article. It started me in the right direction. I'm trying to understand how the security descriptor differs between applications. Maybe user tokens used by access control list?

Comment: Security descriptors assign rights to users, not applications. Think of it like permissions on your files - same basic concept.